# soapui window disappears after few sec

Tags: java, linux, soapui, vmware, mobaxterm

I have installed SoapUI 5.5.0 in rhel 7.8 server and trying to open it via MobaXterm on windows 10 local desktop.
When i run soapui.sh, soapui window opens up and display below messages on server,

```
#./soapui.sh
================================
=
= SOAPUI_HOME = /opt/SoapUI-5.5.0
=
================================
Configuring log4j from [/opt/SoapUI-5.5.0/bin/soapui-log4j.xml]
16:52:38,534 INFO [DefaultSoapUICore] Creating new settings at [/root/soapui-settings.xml]
16:52:39,328 INFO [PluginManager] 0 plugins loaded in 2 ms
16:52:39,328 INFO [DefaultSoapUICore] All plugins loaded
Configuring log4j from [/opt/SoapUI-5.5.0/bin/soapui-log4j.xml]
16:52:39,556 INFO [DefaultSoapUICore] Creating new settings at [/root/soapui-settings.xml]
16:52:39,601 INFO [PluginManager] 0 plugins loaded in 11 ms
16:52:39,601 INFO [DefaultSoapUICore] All plugins loaded
16:52:39,844 INFO [SoapUI] Used java version: 1.8.0_221
```

It opens another window called as 'Stay Tuned!'. As soon as i click on 'Yes, I want to know' or 'skip' button it gives below error on linux server and soapui window disappears.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-12" sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException
at com.smartbear.analytics.impl.SoapUIOSMixpanelProvider.trackError(SoapUIOSMixpanelProvider.java:53)
at com.smartbear.analytics.AnalyticsManager$1.run(AnalyticsManager.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Internal Error
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$new$5(GtkApplication.java:158)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:140)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:278)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.lambda$initFx$2(JFXPanel.java:232)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Its a vm on vmware platform and have driver as below.

```
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: VMware SVGA II Adapter
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
I/O ports at 1070 [size=16]
Memory at e8000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
Memory at fe000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8M]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at c0400000 [disabled] [size=32K]
Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=00 <?>
Capabilities: [44] PCI Advanced Features
Kernel driver in use: vmwgfx
Kernel modules: vmwgfx
```

I have below libgl related packages installed on server.

```
# rpm -qa |grep -i libGL
libglvnd-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64
libglvnd-opengl-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64
mesa-libGL-18.3.4-10.el7.x86_64
mesa-libglapi-18.3.4-10.el7.x86_64
libglvnd-glx-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64
libglvnd-egl-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64
libglvnd-gles-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64
libglvnd-core-devel-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64
mesa-libGLU-devel-9.0.0-4.el7.x86_64
libglvnd-devel-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64
mesa-libGL-devel-18.3.4-10.el7.x86_64
mesa-libGLU-9.0.0-4.el7.x86_64
```

Can you please let me know how to fix this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The below line in `/opt/SoapUI-5.5.0/bin/soapui.sh` was uncommented to disable the browser component.  After his, the SoapUI was no longer crashing as before.

```
#uncomment to disable browser component
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsoapui.browser.disabled=true"
```